# Azure Machine Learning - Serialization error

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have tried to create a predictive webservice (following the movie recommender tutorial) but when I run the predective experiment I get an error:

**Model could not be deserialized because it is likely serialized with an older serialization format. Please retrain and re-save the model. . ( Error 0082 )**

Have you any idea?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to retrain the model?

Answer (score 1):

For recommendation, please replace "Score module" in predictive experiment with "Score Recommendation Module" as shown in the video https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Windows-Azure/Building-a-Recommender-System-in-Azure-ML-Studio - look at the time elapse 2:38